# Kendo Context menu anchored with Right to left

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-contextmenu

I am trying to use Kendo Context menu with Kendo treeview, the issue is when the body is right-to-left (has class "k-rtl") the position of the context menu is wrong. and to make sure it is not from my code i tried to changed one of simple examples from Kendo website and found same result, the example I had modifed can be found on http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU.

Any Idea how to fix this !!!
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like correct behavior to me. Here is a workaround that you can use:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU/2

Comment: yes, the example is working, but still if i change the target to be list not a div, the position of menu is still incorrect as it shows under the items, please check http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU/5. however this is can be solved by setting the filter value

Comment: and also, its always docked to the right side for all levels. check http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU/6

Answer (score 0):

after trying many scenarios, I found that there are incorrect behaviour which i can not explain (if anyone can please), however, i can make it run by setting filter to a span or anchor elements which are inside the list items (not div not paragraph !!!)

For Span element (working): http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU/6

for Paragraph element (not working): http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUVU/7

if anyone has an idea why this happens, please explain